# Can't match (.txt) file origin in Excel

Tags: excel, unicode, import

I am wondering if anybody know about the character issue.
I am trying to import a text file to Excel, which the file format is coded in Unicode/ISO-10646. It has Japanese characters. However, when I am clicking import in Excel and selecting "file origin" I can't find this Unicode/ISO-10646 which makes the characters not displaying correctly (I tried selecting UTF8, ANSI and so forth).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would have thought that UTF-8 would work. Are you sure that your import file is in the correct format?

Comment: J Brazier: Thank you for your input. You could have been right, I luckily found another version with UTF-8 encoding instead.